# Using CartThrob with PayPal Express (error 10004), is there a way to view long/full error messages?

Tags: cartthrob, paypal, paypal-express-checkout

I'v run into a sudden issue with CartThrob and PayPal Express in which it is giving me the following short error message:

`error 10004: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.`

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time troubleshooting this issue because error 10004 can have a multitude of reasons for showing up but I can't find the specific issue without seeing the "long" error message.  Is there a way to see the "long" error message with CartThrob natively?  Or barring that, some way to see it through the PayPal developer site side?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out CartThrob does give the long error message, but not the short one.  The short error message can be added to the error output by editing the Cartthrob_paypal_express.php file in the payment gateways folder and adding $transaction['S_SHORTMESSAGE0']to the error_message key on line 399.

In my case, my issue ended up being this:

> Error code: 10004
>
> Short message: Internal error
>
> Long message: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.

It is confusing because PayPal sometimes gives the same long message as the short message with the same error code, thus making it look like there is no long message attached.

Unfortunately, I still do not have any more information on how to fix my problem.